# Perflib errors & PerfNet error in a sharepoint web front end server

Tags: 2013, performance, windows-server-2012-r2

in a wfe server below error messages occurred when i remove spfarm user from local administrator group of wfe servers.

with spfarm user there are two services running in these servers

-sharepoint Timer service

without adding spfarm user in local administrator group how to solve these errors?

1008:

The Open Procedure for service ".NETFramework" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

1021:

Windows cannot open the 32-bit extensible counter DLL ASP.NET_2.0.50727 in a 64-bit environment. Contact the file vendor to obtain a 64-bit version. Alternatively, you can open the 32-bit extensible counter DLL by using the 32-bit version of Performance Monitor. To use this tool, open the Windows folder, open the Syswow64 folder, and then start Perfmon.exe.

1018:

Disabled performance counter data collection for this session from the "ASP.NET_2.0.50727" service because the performance counter library for that service has generated one or more errors. The errors that forced this action have been written to the application event log.

1008:

The Open Procedure for service "BITS" in DLL "C:\Windows\System32\bitsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

1008:

The Open Procedure for service "FIMSynchronizationService" in DLL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\Bin\mmsperf.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

2004:

Unable to open the Server service performance object. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the status code.

1010:

The Collect Procedure for the "C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv" service in DLL "Spooler" generated an exception or returned an invalid status. The performance data returned by the counter DLL will not be returned in the Perf Data Block. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the exception code or status code.

1008:

The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL "C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.

Comment: hi how to solve these errors related preflib , prefnet

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still having those issues but share with us if you got them fixed!

I was/am having the same problems, but I could get rid of one of them:

- **1010**: I simply started the Print Spooler Service (and set to start automatically). - I haven't had any problem by starting this service

According to a comment in [this site](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-1010-source-Perflib-eventno-853-phase-1.htm), you could disable the performance counters for this Spooler by using **exctrlst.exe** - a Microsoft tool ([read more](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2010/03/04/two-minute-drill-disabled-performance-counters-and-exctrlst-exe/)) that can be downloaded [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/exctrlst/1.00.0.1/nt5/en-us/exctrlst_setup.exe).

You probably have seen the [Event Id site](http://www.eventid.net/) but I think it is worth mentioning again for Event Id errors.

Comment: hi still i am getting these errors, i will try to start spooler service and check the results.

Answer (score 1):

The WSS_WPG group is missing permissions on the two Current Control Set Services keys. Here is how to fix this:

Navigate to the following two registry locations:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BITS\Performance
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WmiApRpl\Performance

Now grant Read permissions to WSS_WPG group on each of the above keys.